# Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.8. in android studio how can I fix it?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, version, flutter-channel

After switched to branch 'stable' flutter channel

The following is the build issue.

Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.8.

```
output: ../../third_party/dart/third_party/pkg/collection/lib/src/utils.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.8.
// Copyright (c) 2014, the Dart project authors. Please see the AUTHORS file
^
../../third_party/dart/third_party/pkg/collection/lib/src/wrappers.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.8.
// Copyright (c) 2013, the Dart project authors. Please see the AUTHORS file
^
../../third_party/dart/third_party/pkg/collection/lib/src/functions.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.8.
// Copyright (c) 2016, the Dart project authors. Please see the AUTHORS file
^
```

Comment: Post error messages and your question directly into the body. Additionally, share your `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: I added the pubspec.yaml as an image

Comment: Post error messages and your question directly into the body of your question using the formatting tools provided and share the output of `flutter channel`.

Comment: Check this. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61847

Comment: I was facing the same problem. Simply use 'flutter clean' and then the 'flutter run' command, and all the problems are resolved automatically.

Comment: please do try "flutter clean" and then "flutter run" before you do any unnessasary steps...  It worked for me ...

Comment: I've voted to reopen this - while it appears to be a specific configuration issue, this error can come about from a more general situation of Flutter channel being messed up.
If I could add an answer it would be to do the following (which just fixed this for me) : 1. `flutter --version` # check version, 2. `flutter channel stable`, 3. `flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 31):

### Why?

This happens, because the your specified language version is higher than the one declared in the `.dart_tool` directory (specifically in the `package_config.json` file).

### Solution

You can either delete the folder manually or let Flutter tools do it for you. Run `flutter clean` from the terminal or, if using Android Studio, go to `Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Clean`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had Flutter and Dart installed seperately

1. Dart(Flutter) - v2.19.2
2. Dart - v2.17.6

When I run `dart` command, it uses `2.Dart`, which is outdated
I removed by `brew uninstall dart`, and after restarting terminal, it uses `flutter dart` instead of `dart` which is latest version

Comment: This! Thank you for this, I had been struggling with this issue for two hours!

Answer (score 2):

## Cause

One of your packages in pubspec.yaml is requiring dart version up that you have installed. For example, I face this issue withe analyzer package.
In my pubspec

```
analyzer: ˆ3.3.1
```

So I ve run

```
flutter version
Answer
Tools • Dart 2.13.3
```

But as you [can see here version 3.3.1 require Dart Tools 2.14](https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer/versions)

[image]

## Solution

Discover which package version in incompatible with your dart

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter clean` and then `flutter --version` command from the terminal:

[image: terminal execution of aforementioned commands]

Then, check the flutter version
in `pubspec.yml` (here it is `1.22.5`) and change the version to match the one from the terminal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, solved my issue by following these steps. Should be marked as correct answer.

Comment: I realize this is an older post, but I'm confused about the comparison of the version of flutter to the version in the pubspec.yaml. From [the Dart Docs](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#version) indicate the version in the pubspec is for your package and not the version of flutter. Am I mistaken?

Comment: yeah, i don't know what he is trying to do

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a package needed a mininum Dart version higher than the app's one (it's at the bottom of your pubspec.lock).
Solution: downgrade package's version.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error yesterday and I fixed it.

This error came when you switch the version of flutter from `1.17.5` (stable channel) to `1.20.?` (dev channel).

To fix it, just create a new project using the last version installed on your PC and copy & paste all the files.

The problem comes from the `pubspec.lock` file because of the versions.

So in conclusion, if you changed the version of Flutter, just create another project and copy the necessary files.

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.47.3)

Comment: [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

Comment: I updated the version - same error message accross the flutter project apps.ERROR: Could not find method android() for arguments [build_1rg1v59oeriv4kmihpnqlgtzy$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure4@d963f4d] on project ':@react-native-community_async-storage' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: firstly, try create a new project(simple flutter project) , run it and see if there is an error or it works. post comment when its done

Comment: Hi, the issue seems to be in Android Studio where I cannot find the issue. I connected the emulator to my VS codes and it works. thanks @Noreddine Doudine Lam for your help.

Comment: I had same issue. juse goto Tools, flutter >> flutter clean, then run the project. It should work isa.

Comment: @waleed.makarem thanks, your solution worked.  You should post it as the answer.