# What is the functionality of .dart_tool folder in a Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I encountered this folder `.dart_tool`. I am able to find the uses of each folder and files, except this one. I want to know what purpose does this folder serves.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As *@Shri* noted in his answer, the [Flutter documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/private-files#the-rules) says:

> The `.dart_tool` directory, which is new in Dart *2*, is used by pub and other tools. It replaces the `.pub` directory as of the *2.0.0-dev.32.0* SDK release.

However, I would also add that it contains a `package_config.json` file that specifies packages' locations and versions (which could cause a problem that I addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64821026/9335767)), as well as Flutter build caches (in a `flutter_build` directory).

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/private-files#the-rules),

> The .dart_tool directory, which is new in Dart 2, is used by [pub](https://pub.dev/) and other tools. It replaces the .pub directory as of the 2.0.0-dev.32.0 SDK release.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who wonders what is `pub`, It is the package repository for flutter and Dart Applications.

A `Package Repository` is a place where all the packages (like libraries, jars) are stored in the internet (once downloaded they may get stored in the local machine and then we call it a local repository).