# Flutter: Open android module in Android Studio for package

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

After forking a Flutter package from GitHub, and try to edit it, then when I click "Open Android module in Android Studio" it opens /example/android instead of /android folder!
[image]

Q: How to open /android folder of a package for editing?

Edit: steps I did

Step 1
[image: Step 1]

Step 2
[image: Step 2]

Step 3
[image: Step 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would open both `example/android/` & `android/` folders. Look carefully in the project pane.

I created a new Flutter Plugin Project and did `Open Android module in Android Studio`. Here is how it looks: `app/` is from `example/android/` & `test_plugin/` is from `android/`.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, always I click "Open Android module in Android Studio " it opens only one Android studio project with example/android/ folder.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of project pane? It opens both for me. It is actually the one that should be opened. It opens the example with the plugin code as dependency

Comment: I have edited my question by adding Screenshots, please take a look

Comment: Try this: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#step-2b-add-android-platform-code-ktjava

Comment: I was already on this page, but this can't solve the problem, alright thank you, I think I should reinstall Android Studio because it lagging sometimes, and the problem probably comes from it.

Comment: @TirthPatel Same problem, the example project is the only module. Try cloning flutter_nfc_kit and open ./example/android. It works for newer projects, or projects I create myself. But this one stubbern project does not... :(

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue myself (again).

As pointed out by [@TirthPatel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68699564/4628115) (see comments), there is a Flutter suggested way of opening the project via Android Studio, see [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#step-2b-add-android-platform-code-ktjava), i.e.

#### Which file do I open?

Via Welcome Screen or `File > Open`, select the `build.gradle` file located in `/path-to-plugin/example/android/gradle.build`

#### No libraries/modules shown except `app`

This is a precautionary set of steps, one that I haven't resolved to a single action to address the problem.

You may find `.idea` folders, and `.dart-tool`.

- `.idea` contains IDE specific configurations, etc (see [this](https://droidrant.com/where-is-idea-folder-in-android-studio/) or [this](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207097529-What-is-the-idea-folder-) for some more info, though not specific for Android Studio)
- `.dart-tool` contains dart related configurations and pre-build files (via `build-runner`, locales via `i18n`, etc. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63510246/what-is-the-functionality-of-dart-tool-folder-in-a-flutter-application) or [here](https://medium.com/@MrArc/dart-package-files-and-folder-components-explained-cbfdf8da53e7) for more info)

*Note: these can be/are generated*

I deleted `.idea` and `.dart-tool` folders in

- `/path-to-plugin/`
- `/path-to-plugin/android`
- `/path-to-plugin/example`
- `/path-to-plugin/example/android`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Right click the .iml file in Android directory, and
2. in the right click menu select flutter->Open for editing in Android Studio.