# Flutter and Dark SDK path not changing in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I use 2 versions of Flutter for 2 different projects. I have created 2 different paths for different versions in [Developer Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfilu.png)

I work on both projects every day but yesterday, suddenly Android Studio starting using the SDK from the default Flutter folder; It shows dart 2.12.2 & Flutter 2.0.3 in preferences but uses 2.10.5 & Flutter 1.22.6 while building.
[Preferences screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYEkB.png)

```
../../Developer/flutter_2.0.3/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.10.
```

Even changing path in local.properties didn't help.

Comment: Hi @Deep Rodge! The question seems like a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63182015/error-the-specified-language-version-is-too-high-the-highest-supported-languag). Please take a look, hopefully it resolves your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.8. in android studio how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63182015/error-the-specified-language-version-is-too-high-the-highest-supported-languag)