# Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13

Tags: flutter, dart

I downgrade Flutter to 2.2.3 from 2.5.2 for a reason.

Now:  `Flutter version 2.2.3` and `Dart version 2.13.4`

in pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

When I run the project it works but I get this message from the console:

```
Failed to precompile devtools:devtools:
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shelf_proxy-1.0.1/lib/shelf_proxy.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2014, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/http.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2013, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/client.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/exception.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2014, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/request.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2013, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/response.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/streamed_request.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/base_client.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/base_request.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/base_response.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63182015/error-the-specified-language-version-is-too-high-the-highest-supported-languag) is what it says: "`flutter clean`, then run the project." it doesn't fix the problem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.8. in android studio how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63182015/error-the-specified-language-version-is-too-high-the-highest-supported-languag)

Comment: @MichalKarbownik No. Read the question carefully, especially the last lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**:

Delete `pubspec.lock` file.

Then run ,

```
flutter clean
```

and

```
flutter pub get
```

**Solution 2**:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Disclaimer: When running the command above, have a really fast internet connection or be ready to lose hours of productive time. ( This will redownload every package installed on your pc, and I mean each and all of the versions of each package)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't fix it. I still get the same message.

Comment: @zeed check the 2nd solution

Comment: Solution 2 worked, thank you. I wish you would warn before running the code. lol. After seeing this answer for others, I think it would be useful to point out that the process will take a very long time before running the code, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219256/14701468).

Comment: @zeed, You are welcome. LOL. Good idea. I added a disclaimer.

Comment: I got same problem, but in my case neither solution 1 and 2 worked :/

Comment: @testerino ask your question in a new thread with the your log

Comment: did you find a solution ? @testerino

Comment: Idk why, but it solved itself randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above and nothing helped.

I then decided to make sure I was on the very latest Android Studio (I stay pretty current anyway) and then update the few Plugins that I use.  I installed the Android Studio patch, and checked for updates after just to be safe and it showed an update now available so I installed it.

Then I made sure all my plugins were up to date.  They already were, as I had updated them recently too.

After doing this I was now able to run devtools... finally.