# Flutter error "Failed to precompile devtools:devtools:"

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, devtools

I use Android Studio to run my app on a iOS simulator and I keep getting "Failed to precompile devtools:devtools:" and "Error: The specified language version is too high. " error. It used to work properly before and I think I was switching Flutter SDK in other projects. It may (or not) cause this issue. How can I fix it?

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           39.1s
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61717/ZX0bcRLAvGE=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 11...
flutter: LoginLocale is en
flutter: Device connectivity status: ConnectivityResult.wifi
Failed to precompile devtools:devtools:
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shelf_proxy-1.0.1/lib/shelf_proxy.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2014, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/http.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2013, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/client.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/exception.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2014, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/request.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2013, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/response.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/streamed_request.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/base_client.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/base_request.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/base_response.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.13.
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
^
```

Comment: Hi @Boris! The question seems like a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63182015/error-the-specified-language-version-is-too-high-the-highest-supported-languag). Please take a look, hopefully it resolves your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.8. in android studio how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63182015/error-the-specified-language-version-is-too-high-the-highest-supported-languag)