# The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 3.0

Tags: flutter, dart, fvm

I'm using fvm to use a later version of flutter (`3.15.0-15.2.pre`) than my global version (`3.10.6`). I've ran `fvm use 3.15.0-15.2.pre` and my project is using that.

I have updated my pubspec.yaml with this:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'
```

flutter `3.15.0-15.2.pre` should definitely be using dart > 3.1.

But I'm getting:

> Error (Xcode):
> .dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart:1:1: Error: The
> specified language version is too high. The highest supported language
> version is 3.0

I'm doing everything to make sure it is using fvm dart.

I've run `fvm flutter clean`, `fvm flutter pub get` and `.fvm/flutter_sdk/bin/flutter run --flavor development --dart-define-from-file "lib/config/environment_strings_dev.json" --target "lib/main_development.dart"`.

Yet I still get the error.

Is this error not to do with the dart version being too low, but `3.15.0-15.2.pre` uses a high enough dart version?

I've seen [Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.8. in android studio how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63182015/3935156) But deleting the .dart_tool directory doesn't work.

`flutter doctor` shows my global flutter version not my project version so `fvm` isn't working.

It runs on the android emulator but not the ios simulator.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with iOS only. Android version is working well...

Comment: Did you solve this error? If you can share the answer it would be great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to fix this issue by setting the path to the flutter version I was using on Xcode and you can do this by doing the following

1. open your project in XCode
2. Click on your project Target
3. Click on Build settings
4. Search for FLUTTER_ROOT and paste the path to flutter there...

Hopefully, This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried all the steps but it didn't help when I checked my `pubspec.yaml` file I was overriding one dependency as:

```
dependency_overrides:
   platform: ^3.1.0
```

I removed it and the error is gone.